# How can I queue up stalker blink?

Tags: starcraft-2

Check out [this HuskyStarcraft video segment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmRTn1pKtzs&t=19m14s) (if you don't get the link to the right time, it's at 19m15s)... how on Earth does Grubby get his stalkers to blink so ridiculously quickly one after the other?

Comment: There is a tutorial on the Starcraft Master map from Blizzard.

Comment: @ayckoster - I don't know what that is... could you provide a link, or if it's in-game, tell me how to find it?

Comment: Look at my answer, it is quite hard to miss once you know what to look for :)

Comment: Very quick tutorial for smart blinking here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQJHr7lQlOs&t=48s

Comment: @ayckoster - OK, that was clear :) Upvoted, and thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common stalker micro technique, especially useful for scaling cliffs in a group and other precision-demanding blinking.

Order your stalkers to move to a location, then use shift to queue a command to blink from there to your desired target. This way, the entire group will blink, but each unit will do so only when it is in the location you determined with the first move order, ensuring that all Stalkers reach the intended destination.

So in the video, the player right clicked the end of the near ramp, then shift+[blink hotkey]+left clicked the far ramp.

Comment: You need to shift+right click after the blink command, or there won't be room for the stalkers that come later to blink up.

Comment: It's also rather hard to get right. More often than not, half your stalkers will end up not blinking to the right spot.

Answer (score 12):

There is a tutorial in the official **Starcraft Master** map from Blizzard. Here is how you access it.

- Search for "starcraft master" and open a custom game.

[image]

- Select round 20 "Blink Train"

[image]

- Try to execute the tips in the Tips section

[image]